# Detect a file overwrite so I can delete the original first

Tags: c#, mef, appdomain, filesystemwatcher

I've been using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633140/MEF-and-AppDomain-Remove-Assemblies-On-The-Fly) tutorial on MEF and loading assemblies on-the-fly and, for the most part, it seems to work. There is just one problem however. To replace an existing assembly with a new version and have the shadow copy and MEF pick up the change you have to actually delete the original *and then copy the new version*. You can't simply drag the new version into the watched folder and have it work.

From the article:

> The reason for the double runner.Recompose() calls is that the Exports signature for the DLL matches the previous version and MEF doesn't see a change since it doesn't look at FileInfo for differences. This then tells the AppDomain that the DLL hasn't changed either and the ShadowCopyFiles doesn't kick in to make that change. The simple workaround is to delete the original, recompose, put the new one in place, and recompose one more time. The only disadvantage I can see in this is the performance of the application will drop momentarily during the recompose.

Their only disadvantage misses what I think is the much bigger disadvantage of not being able to drag-and-drop overwrite the original.

Is there any way around this? Is it possible to detect and overwrite and delete the original first? Or some other way of forcing it to notice the difference?

Comment: I would try using a filesystemwatcher and set the NotifyFilter to LastWrite so it picks up the overwrite. Then you can copy the new file out to a temp directory, delete and recompose, and move it back in and recompose. Hopefully there's a better way, though.